# MongoDb RestAPI query $match above/below $lookup changes results

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a pretty simple MongoDb query using $lookup and $match. My issue is I can't determine the right location for the $match in the query. If I put the $match above the $lookup, I get the expected (filtered correctly by $match) results back but they do not include the "world" array of linked docs. If I put the $match below the query, I get all parent records including the "world" array of linked docs, but the $match did not work.

What am I doing wrong?...

```
server.get(`${routePfx}/${model}s/with-linked`, function (req, res, next) {
    console && console.log('Finding all with linked names ' + model.toUpperCase() + 's...');
    db.collection(model).aggregate(
        {
            "$lookup": {
                from: "world",
                localField: "worldId",
                foreignField: "_id",
                as: "world"
            }
        },
        { "$match": { "del": false } }
    ).toArray(function (err, docs) {
        res.json(201, docs);
        next();
    });
});
```

**EDIT: I found it!** Do you notice the tiny difference?...

```
server.get(`${routePfx}/${model}/:id/with-linked`, function (req, res, next) {
    console && console.log('Finding ' + model.toUpperCase() + ' by Id with linked names...');
    db.collection(model).aggregate([
        { "$match": { "_id": new ObjectId(req.params.id) } },
        {
            "$lookup": {
                from: "world",
                localField: "worldId",
                foreignField: "_id",
                as: "world"
            }
        }
    ]).toArray(function (err, docs) {
        res.json(201, docs);
        next();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The aggregate function needs an array...

```
server.get(`${routePfx}/${model}/:id/with-linked`, function (req, res, next) {
    console && console.log('Finding ' + model.toUpperCase() + ' by Id with linked names...');
    db.collection(model).aggregate([
        { "$match": { "_id": new ObjectId(req.params.id) } },
        {
            "$lookup": {
                from: "world",
                localField: "worldId",
                foreignField: "_id",
                as: "world"
            }
        }
    ]).toArray(function (err, docs) {
        res.json(201, docs);
        next();
    });
});
```

Comment: Aggregate should work the same with/without array for your case. I noticed you change the $match stage from posted question to answer. Can you please verify you had the right $match stage ?

Comment: No the array was absolutely necessary. I simply moved $match to top and added the array wrapper and it works as expected :-)